# Select single option in SelectField redux-form-material-ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I have some forms in my redux app. I use `redux-form-material-ui` as well. I'd like SelectFields that have just one option to be set by default to that option. Is the only way to do this by setting `initialValues` while constructing the form component?

Comment: Your question is way too vague and broad for anyone to understand your issue and be able to assist you. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really simple. You just have to follow the `redux-form` flow properly and call `onChange` defined by `Field` from `redux-form`.

```
import React from 'react';

import { SelectField as MUISelectField } from "redux-form-material-ui";

export class SelectField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.chooseSingleOption();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.children !== this.props.children) {
      this.chooseSingleOption();
    }
  }

  chooseSingleOption() {
    const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);
    if (children.length === 1) {
      this.props.input.onChange(children[0].props.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MUISelectField {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the answer seems to be "No". At least it doesn't seem to be as easy as just passing a prop.

Material-ui (the original, not the Redux-form variation) [doesn't support the `defaultValue` option for SelectField](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/5254). I also found a [similar thread for Redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui/issues/81).

You could probably still solve it if you always have the data for `SelectField` options in an array. Then you could maybe have function that turns that array into an array of `MenuItem`s.

```js
// example option data
const optionDataArray = [{ value: "first option", key: 0 }, { value: "second option", key: 1 }];
const toMenuItem = menuData =>
     (<MenuItem value={value} key={key} primaryText={ value } />)
  );
```

Then you could render them like

```js
<SelectField value={ 
    optionDataArray.length === 1 ? 
       optionDataArray[0].value :
       null
 } >
  { optionDataArray.map(toMenuItem) } 
</SelectField>
```

I haven't tried this, but hopefully this makes the one-item SelectFields controlled components with pre-selected input. And I'm hoping the null value will interpreted as if we didn't provide anything at all.

But if the second assumption/hope isn't true, then you could perhaps make a function that like this:

```js
const getSelectFieldValueProp = allOptionData => {
  if(allOptionData.length == 1) {
    return { value: allOptionData[0].value }
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

And use it like

```js
<SelectField {...getSelectFieldValueProp(optionDataArray) } >
  { optionDataArray.map(toMenuItem) } 
</SelectField>
```

That way only the one-item SelectFields should get the value prop set.